# Composer could not find a composer.json

Tags: php, json, composer-php, osx-mavericks

I tried to install composer via brew per:

In `usr/local/bin` (which was not on Mavericks and I had to make it personally) I did.

```
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install josegonzalez/php/composer
```

I can run `php composer.phar`, but when I do `php composer.phar install`, I get the error:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/local/bin
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section`

So I go to the `https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md`. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> ".json" and nothing's there. Seriously composer?

EDIT:
What I was trying to do was to have `composer` executable vs `php composer.phar`. This works at this point from this now.

Comment: Because; You installed `composer` globally and can be called everywhere but when ever you call `composer install`, `composer` will search for the `composer.json` file in the same directory and not globally.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Getting Started" page is the introduction to the documentation. Most documentation will start off with installation instructions, just like Composer's do.

The page that contains information on the `composer.json` file is [located here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) - under "Basic Usage", the second page.

I'd recommend reading over the documentation in full, so that you gain a better understanding of how to use Composer. I'd also recommend removing what you have and following the installation instructions provided in the documentation.

Answer (score 18):

To install composer and add to your global path:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

run these in terminal. It does say if you get an error that usr doesn't exist, you do need to manually make it. I know an answer was selected, so this is for anyone who may see this in the future, as i am sometimes, and don't want to be advised to visit yet another site. Its simple just two lines, might have to be in sudo if you have permission error

Answer (score 14):

You are in wrong directory. cd to your project directory then run composer update.

Comment: I had this issue and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I did not copy all project files to the folder where I was running `composer install`. So do:

1. Copy your project files (including the `composer.json`) to folder
2. open CMD (I am using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)), navigate to the new folder, run `composer install` from there
3. It should work or throw errors in case the json file is not correct.

If you just want to make composer run, create a new `composer.json` file with for example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer install`.

Comment: this should be the top answer for this composer question

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same error, and was able to solve it as follows:

1. `composer diagnose` to see if something is wrong with the version of composer installed
2. `composer self-update` to install the latest version
3. `composer update` to update your `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution is install via this command :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

To install package it's very simple :

```
 composer global require "phpunit/php-invoker=1.1.*"
```

[Ref : composer web site](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using homestead. 
 `cd ~/Homestead`and run `composer install`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try updating the composer:

```
sudo composer self-update
```

If that doest works remove composer files & then use:
SSH into terminal & type :

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

If you face an error that says: ***PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar***

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

To install package use:

```
composer global require "package-name"
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? If Composer would not been installed before, how should the error message from the question occur? Also, why should one install Composer this way once more if it was installed before using Brew?

Comment: The solution is to install a fresh version of Composer.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer by editing it. Why should installing a fresh version help? Also, why not update the existing version through `self-update` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm in wrong directory,

```
My directory Path
eCommerce-shop/eCommerce
```

I am in inside eCommerce-shop and executing this command composer intsall so that't it throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a file called composer.json
- Make sure the Composer can write in the directory you are looking for.
- Update your composer.

  This worked for me

Comment: For which problem? Have you had a look at the other answers before posting yours?

Comment: This results in `[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]                                        
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON                           
  Parse error on line 1:                                                  
                                                                          
  ^                                                                       
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[`

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to run:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

You would be face this error : Composer could not find a composer.json

Comment: Can you explain that further? This looks like a command tied to Laravel. Unless Laravel was installed any other way, there is no way this will do anything

Comment: Yes , this command run first at laravel. If a person forget to run this, (Like me one time when i get project from git forgot to run key:generate) and face to this error : Composer could not find a composer.json.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 0):

2 things to notice; (i did mistake and corrected with step2)

1. might be wrong path of compose.json in docker file. ex; if your compose.json file is not in root of repo.

OR

2. if using any tools to build image, specify relevant path in context.