# Jenkins not using project directory on build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm building my laravel project. In one of my build step, I have a shell script that has `composer install` command there. When I try to build my project. I receive this error:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /usr/bin
```

But I have `composer.json` in my project directory, why is it looking in the `/usr/bin` directory? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Seems like the `composer` command runs from the location where the `composer` binary tool is located which is `/usr/bin` folder.

Maybe your command should be `/usr/bin/composer install`

Comment: I also tried that command, but to no avail. Its really weird that error is showing :(

Comment: Seems to me that you need to re-install the composer and add it to the PATH. 

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900211/composer-could-not-find-a-composer-json

Comment: @aceraven777 Did you manage to solve this?